# Compare Values of 2 Lists C#

Tags: c#, list, compare

I want to compare the values of two lists for a program I'm making. I want it to compare the 1st value of List 1 to the first value of List 2, and then the second value of List 1 to the second value of List 2, and so on.

How would I go about doing this in C#?

Comment: Can we see what you have tried

Comment: We can't help you if you can't show us what you've tried and that you at least researched for some time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a special method for this, called [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
IList<int> myList1 = new List<int>(...);
IList<int> myList2 = new List<int>(...);
if (myList1.SequenceEqual(list2)) {
    ...
}
```

You can do custom comparison of sequences using the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method. For example, to see if any pair is *not* within the difference of three, you can do this:

```
IList<int> myList1 = new List<int>(...);
IList<int> myList2 = new List<int>(...);
if (myList1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => Math.Abs(a - b)).Any(diff => diff > 3)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: We can't educate the children if you give'em candies before dinner. ;)

Comment: Is it possible for me to just get the variable? Because I'm not just wanting to check if it's equal, but I want to see if it's between the range of -3 and +3 (which I know how to do).

Comment: @rcdmk This one is not exactly named for easy searching on, say, google. You need to know where to search to find it.

Comment: @Spl33nMaster You need a different method then - take a look at the update.

Comment: OK, OK... +1 for the `Zip` solution.